# What are the different parts of an image URL, and how to generate new sizes?

Tags: magento-1.9, product-images, media-images, image-resizing

I have an **image URL** like this:

> http://example.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/thumbnail/65x65/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/r/a/random-product_8.jpg

What is the meaning of the **"9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95"** and why is it the same for **all images**?

Also, how can I programmatically create a new size of images (say 120x120) for all of my products?

Answer (score 0):

Use One of any methods do you wants

```
<?php echo Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'thumbnail')->resize(120,120); ?>

<?php echo Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'image')->resize(120,120); ?>

<?php echo Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(120,120); ?>
```

Comment: Thanks, but what about the first part? Do you know what the meaning of the "9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95" is?

Comment: that is a cached image cropped by default

Comment: sorry can't accept the answer, because I don't understand the meaning of all those numbers and letters.  is it like a GUID?

Comment: I never forced you for that. I have posted which i know, Good Day !!!